# Comparing array elements using Unicode

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, unicode

```
Array.prototype.mySort = function (callbackFnc) {

sorted = false;

while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;

    for (var idx = 0; idx < this.length-1; idx++) {
        if (callbackFnc(this[idx],this[idx+1]) <0) {
            sorted = false;

            var comp = this[idx];

            this[idx] = this[idx + 1];

            this[idx + 1] = comp;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Call:

```
     myArray.mySort(function (val1, val2) { return val1 - val2 });
```

So my aim is to sort the elements like If I use array.sort(); The problem is that the actual sort function sorts via unicode. How can sort my array with the help using unicode?

Comment: @Yeah I fixed that, but how can I sort the elements via unicode. I only sort it if the one is lower/higher than the other

Comment: What do you mean "via unicode"? You want to sort by char codes or code points? May be you search for [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)?

Comment: @Arnial Code Points. I think I need localCompare for it. :)